# Three.js: wrong BoundingBox after scaling a geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my scene I have a simple cube:

```
var test = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,10,10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
scene.add(test);
```

This cube is getting traversed/scaled through the user with `THREE.TransformControls`. What I need is the boundingbox of the cube after these interactions. So I'm doing

```
test.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var bb = test.geometry.boundingBox;
bb.translate(test.localToWorld( new THREE.Vector3()));
```

But I always get a wrong boundingbox! The translation is computed correct, but not the scale. The width and heigth of the boundingbox is always 10 ...

Is this a bug or feature? How do I get the correct boundingbox of my cube?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compute the world-axis-aligned bounding box of an object (including its children) like so:

```
var box = new THREE.Box3();
box.setFromObject( object );
```

Have a look at the source code so you understand what it is doing.

three.js. r.60

Comment: I know this function but didn't thought it would solve my problem - it's awesome! I always searched some function to scale my bbox... Many thanks!!