# Three.js - Accurate ray casting for collision detection

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I'm working with Three.js, version **68**. I'm using the same method for collision detection as this guy is using here, which is great most of the time (A big "thank you" goes out to the author!): http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html

Here is a link to the source if you want to download it from github. Just look for **Collision-Detection.html**: https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com

Here is the code that is important to the collision detection:

```
var MovingCube;
var collidableMeshList = [];

var wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
wall.position.set(100, 50, -100);
scene.add(wall);
collidableMeshList.push(wall);
var wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wireMaterial);
wall.position.set(100, 50, -100);
scene.add(wall);

var wall2 = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
wall2.position.set(-150, 50, 0);
wall2.rotation.y = 3.14159 / 2;
scene.add(wall2);
collidableMeshList.push(wall2);
var wall2 = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wireMaterial);
wall2.position.set(-150, 50, 0);
wall2.rotation.y = 3.14159 / 2;
scene.add(wall2);

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,50,50,1,1,1);
var wireMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe:true } );
MovingCube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, wireMaterial );
MovingCube.position.set(0, 25.1, 0);


// collision detection:
//   determines if any of the rays from the cube's origin to each vertex
//      intersects any face of a mesh in the array of target meshes
//   for increased collision accuracy, add more vertices to the cube;
//      for example, new THREE.CubeGeometry( 64, 64, 64, 8, 8, 8, wireMaterial )
//   HOWEVER: when the origin of the ray is within the target mesh, collisions do not occur
var originPoint = MovingCube.position.clone();

for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < MovingCube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
{       
    var localVertex = MovingCube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
    var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( MovingCube.matrix );
    var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( MovingCube.position );

    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
    var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );
    if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) 
        appendText(" Hit ");
}
```

This works great most of the time, but there are times when I can move the cube partially into the wall, and it won't register a collision. For example, look at this image: [image: Collision Detection]

It should say "Hit" in the top-left corner where there are just a bunch of dots, and it's not.
**NOTE:** I also tried his suggestion and did the following, but it didn't seem to help much:

```
THREE.BoxGeometry( 64, 64, 64, 8, 8, 8, wireMaterial ) // BoxGeometry is used in version 68 instead of CubeGeometry
```

Does anyone know how this method could be more accurate? **Another question:** Does anyone know what the following **if** statement is for, i.e. why does the object's distance have to be less than the length of the direction vector?:

```
if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your last question first: that line detects whether the collision happened inside your MovingCube. Your raycasting code casts a ray from the MovingCube's position towards each of its vertices. Anything that the ray intersects with is returned, along with the distance from the MovingCube's position at which the intersected object was found (`collisionResults[0].distance`). That distance is compared with the distance from the MovingCube's position to the relevant vertex. If the distance to the collision is less than the distance to the vertex, the collision happened inside the cube.

Raycasting is a poor method of collision detection because it only detects collisions in the exact directions rays are cast. It also has some additional edge cases. For example, if the ray is cast from inside another object, the other object might not be considered to be colliding. As another example, raycasting in Three.js uses bounding spheres (or, if unavailable, bounding boxes) to calculate ray intersection, so rays can "intersect" with objects even if they wouldn't hit them visually.

If you're only dealing with spheres or upright cuboids, it's straightforward math to check collision. (That's why Three.js uses bounding spheres and bounding boxes - and most applications that need to do collision checking use secondary collision-only geometries that are less complicated than the rendered ones.) Spheres are colliding if the distance between their centers is less than the sum of their radii. Boxes are colliding if the edges overlap (e.g. if the left edge of box 1 is to the left of the right edge of box 2, and the boxes are within a vertical distance the sum of their half-heights and a horizontal distance the sum of their half-lengths).

For certain applications you can also use voxels, e.g. divide the world into cubical units, do box math, and say that two objects are colliding if they overlap with the same cube-unit.

For more complex applications, you'll probably want to use a library like Ammo.js, Cannon.js, or Physi.js.

The reason raycasting is appealing is because it's workable with more complex geometries without using a library. As you've discovered, however, it's less than perfect. :-)

I wrote a book called Game Development with Three.js which goes into this topic in some depth. (I won't link to it here because I'm not here to promote it, but you can Google it if you're interested.) The book comes with sample code that shows how to do basic collision detection, including full code for a 3D capture-the-flag game.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'm trying to get bounding boxes to work using three.js. Basically you can do the following: `object.geometry.computeBoundingBox(); //object is THREE.Mesh` `var objectBoundingBox = object.geometry.boundingBox.clone();`

Then you can do that same thing on another mesh, and do the following to see if they intersect:
`if (object.isIntersectionBox(otherObjectBoundingBox))`

However, that is always true for me! Box3 is the bounding box, and the source is here: [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Box3.js)

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Made a mistake in my previous comment **if** statement. It should be this: `if (objectBoundingBox.isIntersectionBox(otherObjectBoundingBox))`

Comment: I'd just console.log() the boxes you're comparing and try the conditions from the source of isIntersectionBox manually to see what result you get and go from there

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of that bounding box example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0b7kpge/21/). As you can see, the cubes are nowhere near each other, but yet, isIntersectionBox returns true. It seems like the bounding boxes are being computed correctly. I'm not sure what I could do to make it ever false.

Comment: Alright, looks like this post works!: [Three.js: wrong BoundingBox after scaling a geometry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461480/three-js-wrong-boundingbox-after-scaling-a-geometry). Thanks for the idea of using the bounding box =)