# Detect collision between sphere and triangle in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I wish to find whether a triangle collides at all with a sphere, in three.js

I have implemented a method using the raycaster and the sphere's vertices, but it is not working always because the triangle might be "between" 2 of the sphere's vertices and thus, not able to be detected.

I want a perfect mathematical algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I have found the solution :

The algorithm works in **2 phases** :

**Phase 1**

I create 3 lines using the 3 points I have from the triangle :

```
 var line1 = new THREE.Line3(a,b);
 var line2 = new THREE.Line3(a,c);
 var line3 = new THREE.Line3(b,c);

 then I find the closest point from each of these 3 lines, to the center of the sphere :
  
 var closestPoint1 = line1.closestPointToPoint(center, true);
 var closestPoint2 = line2.closestPointToPoint(center, true);
 var closestPoint3 = line3.closestPointToPoint(center, true);

 then I calculate the distance of that point to the center :

 // code for 1 line only

 var distToCenter = closestPoint.distanceTo(center);
 if(distToCenter <= radius){ 
   // we have a collision
 }
```

and that's it for the lines of the triangle. If no line intersects with the sphere, I will check the "body" of the triangle in Phase 2 :

**Phase 2**

I create a THREE.Triangle using the 3 point sof the triangle, then I create a plane using that triangle and finally I find the closest point form the plane to the center of the sphere . If that point "belongs" to the triangle, we have a collision:

```
 var triangle = new THREE.Triangle( a,b,c );
 var plane = triangle.plane();
 var pp, cp;

 var dp = Math.abs(plane.distanceToPoint(center)); 

 if(dp <= radius){ 
   pp = plane.projectPoint(center);
   cp = triangle.containsPoint(pp);
      
   if(cp === true){
       // collision
   }
 }
```

If not collision is detected neither in Phase 1 or phase 2, the triangle does not collide with the sphere.

My solution has worked in my project perfectly.

Please inform for problems you may encounter.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a perfect mathematical algorithm I can recommend you looking at the following page, that covers exactly your problem as far as I understand it: [Three.js - Accurate ray casting for collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697327/three-js-accurate-ray-casting-for-collision-detection)